# comtypes: in call_with_inout, ctypes TypeError: 'c_double' object is not iterable

Tags: python, ctypes, comtypes

Im working with Agilent IVI drivers in Python 2.7.9 and can't seem to get 'proven' code to work on a particular Windows 7 machine. It executes successfully on other machines.

While this issue seems rather limited to one instrument, it appears to be a broader Python issue, so I turn to Stack Overflow for help. Any help or insight would be great.

The following code

```
# Import the TLB

from comtypes.client import GetModule, CreateObject
GetModule('AgInfiniium.dll')

# Pull in the coefficients and classes, we'll need those
from comtypes.gen.AgilentInfiniiumLib import *

# Instantiate the driver
OScope = CreateObject('AgilentInfiniium.AgilentInfiniium')

# Make constants of our settings
Address = "TCPIP0::10.254.0.222::INSTR"
resetOScope = False

# Open a connection to the scope
OScope.Initialize(Address,False,resetOScope,'')

# Make a measurement
print OScope.Measurements.Item("Channel1").ReadWaveformMeasurement(
    MeasFunction=AgilentInfiniiumMeasurementAmplitude, MaxTime=10)
```

yields the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\Aperture\Validation\WMI_BGA_Board\TestMatrixCode\scopeTest2.py", line 29, in <module>
    print OScope.Measurements.Item("Channel1").ReadWaveformMeasurement(MeasFunction=AgilentInfiniiumMeasurementAmplitude ,MaxTime=10)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes-1.1.0-py2.7.egg\comtypes\__init__.py", line 656, in call_with_inout
    rescode = list(rescode)
TypeError: 'c_double' object is not iterable
```

In my limited debugging attempts, I have seen that this `call_with_inout`
function tries to convert my Python arguments into arguments for the following C++ function:

```
public void ReadWaveformMeasurement(
    AgilentInfiniiumMeasurementEnum MeasFunction,
    AgilentInfiniiumTimeOutEnum MaxTime,
    ref double pMeasurement)
```

It's creating some kind of variable for the `pMeasurement` pointer that ends up being type `c_double`, and then complains that it's not iterable.

At this point, this seems like it's local to this machine. I've gone to the extent of uninstalling Python, reinstalling the Agilent driver, and trying two versions of comtypes (1.1.0 and 1.1.1). Yet the problem persists. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the comtypes package, but this particular line in [`_fix_inout_args`](https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/blob/1.1.1/comtypes/__init__.py#L656) (1.1.1 source)  seems to mistakenly assume that a function that has `paramflags` with in-out arguments always returns a tuple of results. But actually, if there's only one output parameter (e.g. `pMeasurement`), it gets returned directly instead of in a tuple.

Comment: For an explanation of `paramflags`, see the section on [function prototypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#function-prototypes) in the ctypes reference. It states that "[f]unctions with output parameters will automatically return the output parameter value if there is a single one, or a tuple containing the output parameter values when there are more than one".